# Stack images on top of cards, but not on top of each other

Tags: flutter, stack

How to make mycard like it? there is a picture above the card

[image]

```dart
return Expanded(
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 20.0,
        runSpacing: 20.0,
        children: food.map((foodItem) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailPage(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // Positioned(
                //   top: -15, // Sesuaikan posisinya
                //   left: 0,
                //   right: 0,
                //   child: Image.asset(
                //     foodItem.image,
                //     height: 90.0, // Sesuaikan tinggi gambar
                //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //   ),
                // ),
                Container(
                  width: 180.0,
                  height: 120.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: foodItem.bgColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          child: Text(
                            foodItem.name,
                            maxLines: 2,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "\$${foodItem.price.toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                              ),
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                // Tambahkan logika favorit di sini
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white, // Warna latar belakang tombol
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle, // Membuat tombol menjadi lingkaran
                                ),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite, // Ikon keranjang
                                  color: Colors.black, // Warna ikon
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem

Comment: Please edit you post to add code fences and language identifier (Dart) so it can be human-readable

Answer (score 1):

On Stack widget, children will render top to bottom, where the last child will show above the previous one.

```
Stack
    ..... background….
    2nd Priority –
    1st priority – front side, on top of other child
```

Now for your case the Item needed to be show image on top of everything, there you can place the image as last child. Also the height of the Item should be the imageSize+topSpace.

```dart
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 40 + 120.0, //control  height of the card
    width: 200,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 40,
          height: 120.0,
          width: 200,
          child: Container(
            width: 180.0,
            height: 120.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.cyanAccent, //  foodItem.bgColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0, // Sesuaikan posisinya
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: 90,
          child: Placeholder(),
          // Image.asset(
          //   foodItem.image,
          //   height: 90.0, // Sesuaikan tinggi gambar
          //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
          // ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```